# EditText empty after phone number query - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have a button inside a Dialog box called `addContact()` that when clicked, it should open my `Contacts` in my Android phone, which it does, and then when I click on a contact, it is supposed to pull the phone number from that contact and put it in my EditText, inside my dialog box, but that doesn't work, it shows a blank `EditText` field. Since the EditText is in a fragment xml (not in my activity xml), I have to use a `LayoutInflator` and put that into a `View` before I instantiate my EditText, so I wonder if that has anything to do with my error. Thing is, I get no crash or error codes, just a blank EditText after I click on a contact. I already inflated the dialog box view in another method (see below), but it was inside a method, so I was worried about scope, so I inflated it again when I needed it inside the `onActivityResult()`. Is that correct? How do I get the phone number to show? Thanks.

EDIT:

If I take out the 2nd inflation:

```
final LayoutInflater inflater = SMSMain.this.getLayoutInflater();
final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_compose_sms, null);
EditText phoneEntry = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_phone);
```

then I get a null pointer at this line, when I use the `EditText` variable from my first inflation:

```
etPhoneNumber.setText(phone);
```

But why would that be null?

**A portion of my activity code, SMSMain.java:**

```
public void composeSMS(View v){

        // build your dialog box
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SMSMain.this);
        // Get the layout inflater & inflate the box
        final LayoutInflater inflater = SMSMain.this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_compose_sms, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.setTitle("Send an SMS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // get phone number and message IDs
                etPhoneNumber = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_phone);
                etMessage = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_message);
                // Turns the entered phone number and message into String
                String phoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim(); 
                // error check to make sure there is input
                if (phoneNumber.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0) 
                    // sends the SMS
                    sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);                
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter a phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        // put all your builders in one create command
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); 
        // show the dialog box
        dialog.show();

    }

    // method for sending the SMS
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {        
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                    new Intent(this, SMSMain.class), 0);                
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
        }

public void addContact(View v) {

        // add a contact. using Android's ContactPicker
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String phone = "";
                try{
                    Uri result = data.getData();
                    // get the contact id from the URI
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                    // query for phone number
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);

                    int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    } else {
                        // Failed
                      }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Failed
                 } finally {
                        if (cursor != null){
                            cursor.close();
                        }
                        final LayoutInflater inflater = SMSMain.this.getLayoutInflater();
                        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_compose_sms, null);
                        EditText phoneEntry = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_phone);
                        phoneEntry.setText(phone);
                        if (phone.length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No phone number found for contact.",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

**My dialog_compose_sms.xml**  (nothing much in my activity.xml, just a "Compose SMS" button.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_button"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="addContact" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sms_phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone" >

        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:padding="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/speech_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:background="@drawable/speech_icon" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mic_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mic_icon" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#e9e9e9"
        android:padding="20dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sms_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"

        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**`onActivityResult` after I deleted the 2nd inflation**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String phone = "";
                try{
                    Uri result = data.getData();
                    // get the contact id from the URI
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                    // query for phone number
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);

                    int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                        System.out.println("Value of phone: " + phone);
                    } else {
                        // Failed
                      }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Failed
                 } finally {

                     System.out.println("I am in finally block");

                     etPhoneNumber.setText(phone, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                     String stringNo = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                     System.out.println("Value of etPhoneNumber: " + stringNo);


                    if (phone.length() == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "No phone number found for contact.",
                                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                     if (cursor != null){
                            cursor.close();
                     }

                 } // end finally
                 break;  
            }
        }
```

**Logcat after deleting the 2nd inflation**

```
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266): Process: org.azurespot.practiceapp, PID: 32266
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1001, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/1343 flg=0x1 }} to activity {org.azurespot.practiceapp/org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms.SMSMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3663)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3706)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:173)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at org.azurespot.practiceapp.sms.SMSMain.onActivityResult(SMSMain.java:135)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5643)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3659)
12-31 21:07:02.430: E/AndroidRuntime(32266):    ... 11 more
12-31 21:07:05.510: I/Process(32266): Sending signal. PID: 32266 SIG: 9
12-31 21:07:05.860: I/PersonaManager(32648): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
12-31 21:07:05.860: D/skia(32648): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 270 
12-31 21:07:05.870: D/skia(32648): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 271 
12-31 21:07:05.880: D/skia(32648): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 272 
12-31 21:07:05.890: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(32648): Parent view is not a TextView
12-31 21:07:05.900: D/skia(32648): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:144 height:144 bitmap id is 273 
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08+13
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): Build Date: 03/20/14 Thu
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): Local Branch: 0320_AU200_patches
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): Remote Branch: 
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): Local Patches: 
12-31 21:07:05.970: I/Adreno-EGL(32648): Reconstruct Branch: 
12-31 21:07:06.010: D/OpenGLRenderer(32648): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: Dialog is visible to user when `onActivityResult` method called ?

Comment: Yes, the dialog box shows, but when I try to get the number from `Contacts` and select a contact, it either goes back to the dialog box with a blank phone number field, or with the 2nd inflation removed, it crashes the app when I try to select a `Contact`. But I know the code is running when onActivityResult() processes, because a log statement shows it does get the phone number okay (the value of `phone` shows up correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I inflated it again when I needed it inside the onActivityResult().
>   Is that correct?

No Because you are inflated new view of layout which is not currently added in AlertDialog, showing to user.

Use same instance `etPhoneNumber` which you are using on positive button click in `onActivityResult()` for showing number to user:

```
finally {
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.close();
           }
          if(dialog.isShowing())
            etPhoneNumber.setText(phone);
           if (phone.length() == 0) {
               Toast.makeText(this, "No phone number found for contact.",
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
        }
```

also move initialization for `etPhoneNumber` and `etMessage` after `builder.setView` of AlertDialog because currently you are initializing both on Send button click.

Comment: Thanks, okay that makes sense. Although the `EditText` was just blank anyway (up to that point), so in theory it seems like it should have worked, since I used the same resource ID... nonetheless, I tried your suggestion and now it crashes when I select a contact, so I know it is something to do with that `EditText` line. I posted my logcat above.

Comment: I just can't figure out what it could be, why won't the number post to the EditText? I know `phone` is a variable with a value, I checked it with a log statement.

Comment: @NoniA.: also move `etPhoneNumber = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_phone);
                etMessage = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sms_message);` lines after  `builder.setView(dialogView);` instead of `onClick` of positive button

Comment: Hi p, thanks, I posted the updated code. Also, I checked those instantiations and they already come after `builder.setView(dialogView);` or did you mean to suggest something else? Ah, nevermind, outside of the `onClick` you meant.

Comment: OMG That worked!!!! I see it now, it WAS an issue of scope. It's always a trick when you make a global variable, you never know if it's taking the value from the right place. Thank you so much!!!! This was a weird one, because everything seemed right. :)